# Can VSCode auto opens the published folder after publish process?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, publish

My task.json file in VSCode is as follows.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "dotnet",
      "task": "build",
      "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "label": "dotnet: build"
    },
    {
      "label": "publish user",
      "command": "dotnet",
      "type": "process",
      "args": [
        "publish",
        "API_V2.sln",
        "-c",
        "Release",
        "-o",
        "../../../../user/Downloads/API_Publish"
      ],
      "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
```

I can publish without any problems. Can the Finder window open automatically after the process is completed?

Answer (score 0):

In your publish user task, add a presentation property within the object.
Inside the presentation property, create a reveal property set to always.
Then, add a postCommand property with an array containing a shell command to open the Finder window.

```
{
  "type": "dotnet",
  "task": "build",
  "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
  "group": {
    "kind": "build",
    "isDefault": true
  },
  "label": "dotnet: build"
},
{
  "label": "publish user",
  "command": "dotnet",
  "type": "process",
  "args": [
    "publish",
    "API_V2.sln",
    "-c",
    "Release",
    "-o",
    "../../../../user/Downloads/API_Publish"
  ],
  "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
  "presentation": {
    "reveal": "always"
  },
  "postCommand": [
    "open ../../../../user/Downloads/API_Publish"
  ]
}
```